# How can i call the variables defined under a class using avariable which is of that class type and is called using another class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have defined 2 classes.

```
class A
 {
    public B[] varA{get;set;}
 }

class B
{
  public string varB{get;set;}
}
```

I have created an object of class A as A newObj = new A();
I need to assign values to the variable defined in class B using this object but

```
newObj.varA.varB
```

is not working. How to call it ?

Comment: `is not working` what does that mean? What behavior you are getting there? What error you are getting

Comment: I was getting a null reference issue, i don't know why but i did not think of initialising it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing what is called a **null reference**.

After object creation,

```
A newObj = new A();
```

newObj's properties remains uninitialized, the `varA` property is a **null reference** until you initialize it like this

```
newObj.varA = new B[1]; //create an array that can hold one B instance and assign it to varA
```

Still, if you access the first element in the array like `varA[0]`, you will find it is a null reference, too! You need to initialize it too.

```
newObj.varA[0] = new B(); //create a B instance and put it to the array
```

Then you can access `varB` using

```
newObj.varA[0].varB = "Hello World!";
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an option to use Inheritance between those classes.

```
Class B
{
String varB;
}
Class A:B
{
```

String varA;
    }

Then you can assign values to class B using Class A object.
`A newObj = new A();`

```
newObj.varB="Value";
```

Comment: Say if A is "Order" and B is "OrderLine", you don't want Order to *inherit* from OrderLine, you want Order to *contain* several OrderLines.